# How to use TextTestRunner class from Python unittest module in failfast mode?

Tags: python, unit-testing

All I found in documentation of `unittest` module is [description](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner) of `TextTestRunner`'s constructor and the following sample code using its `run()` method:
`unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)`

I would like to know how I can use `TextTestRunner` in failfast mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructor of `TextTestRunner` class has [`failfast`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/unittest/runner.py#l128) parameter which is not shown in the constructor's documentation.

UPDATE

I raised bug [17871](http://bugs.python.org/issue17871) and it's fixed now what you can verify at http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner