# Android Monkeyrunner's: Can it stop at first error?

Tags: android, unit-testing, jython, monkeyrunner

I'm unit testing an Android app using **Monkeyrunner** with Jython on Eclipse.

- Eclipse: 4.2.1
- Eclipse plugin PyDev: 2.7.1
- Jython: 2.5.3

When running the tests I would like it to **fail at the first assertion failure.**

Shortened test script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
#    unittest.main()

    mDevice = getConnection()
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()

    #----------------------------------------------
    suite0001 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test_TEST0001)
    suite.addTest(suite0001)    

    runner.run(suite)
```

I've read about setting some failfast parameter on this discussion: [How to use TextTestRunner class from Python unittest module in failfast mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068216/how-to-use-texttestrunner-class-from-python-unittest-module-in-failfast-mode)

So I try to set this parameter like this:

```
    ...
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(failfast=True)
    ...
```

However, when running the script, it fails:

```
  File "c:\svnrepository\x\trunk\JythonProject\src\main.py", line 1361, in <module>
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(failfast=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'failfast'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> -f, --failfast Stop the test run on the first error or failure.
>
> New in version 2.7: The command-line options -b, -c and -f were added.

failfast was added in 2.7, `monkeyrunner` uses 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this mean that there is no other way to stop at first failure with monkeyrunner?